# Extract specific column from a Mysql Table to a CSV file - PDP - MYSQL- PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo

I have written the following code to extract a column from a Mysql Table to a CSV file.
When I ran the script it throws the following error.

Warning: `fputcsv()` expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in

on this line `fputcsv($data, $row);` Is it problem with the **PDO**?

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".date('m.d.Y').'.csv');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

define('STOREDIR','upload/csv');
    define('ABPATH', dirname(__file__) . '/'); //do not modify this

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT fname from abcgroup where group_id='2'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
    $stmt->bindColumn('fname', $fname);

    $filename = ABPATH.STOREDIR.date('m.d.Y').'.csv';
    $data = fopen($filename, 'w');
       while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            fputcsv($data, $row);
        }
        fclose($data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `PDO::FETCH_BOUND`, `$stmt->fetch()` returns either `true` or `false`, not the row of results. The results are stored in the variables bound with `$stmt->bindColumn`. So you need to use:

```
fputcsv($data, array($fname));
```

But you could just use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` or `PDO::FETCH_NUM` so that `$row` will contain the array of columns. Then you can use it in `fputcsv()` as you have.

Comment: this returns nothing in the CSV file

Comment: Sorry, I meant `array($fname)`.

Comment: Do you see the names if you do `echo $fname`?

Comment: My query returns Showing rows 0 - 13 (14 total, Query took 0.0021 sec)  in phpmyadmin

Comment: @user580950 Please do the `echo $fname` and if it works, check the returned value of `fputcsv()` (could also just add an echo in front of it and see if it returns the number of bytes written)

Comment: hey that worked after debugging now the problem is all records are displayed in a single row, how to display in multiple rows, right now it shows http://prntscr.com/do5oma

Comment: I can't think of a reason for that. `fputcsv` writes a separate line each time, I don't know why they would all end up in the same row in the spreadsheet. What do you see if you open it up in a text editor instead?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `PDO::FETCH_BOUND`, your call to `fetch()` won't return a data row. It will only return `true` if success and bind the column content to your variables. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php):

> `PDO::FETCH_BOUND`: returns TRUE and assigns the values of the columns in your result set to the PHP variables to which they were bound with the PDOStatement::bindColumn() method

If you want to put the contents of `fname` in your CSV, use this instead:

```
fputcsv($data, [$fname]);
```

Or use a different fetch style to have the row array, such as `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

Comment: this returns nothing in the CSV file

Comment: @user580950 only if `$fname` is empty then. Can you check if your query returns proper results?

Comment: My query returns Showing rows 0 - 13 (14 total, Query took 0.0021 sec)  in phpmyadmin

Answer (score -1):

`$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT fname from abcgroup where group_id='2'");`

Here is the problem

Check the above line ( table name and other details of your table and database like column name and row etc...  )

Comment: What's the problem with that query, it looks fine to me.